# How do I combine these 6 SQL queries together without errors?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot, aggregate-functions

I'd like to make a JOIN statement with all the above information into 1 query instead of having 6. I tried several things but I always get errors especially: "ambiguous name column” error for the member_casual table that appears in all 3 datasets... I tried finding answers online but they're too complex for my current knowledge and don't work for my specific problem.

```
SELECT COUNT (member_casual)
FROM `test-project-355707.cyclistic_trips.01-23`
WHERE member_casual = "casual";
SELECT COUNT (member_casual)
FROM `test-project-355707.cyclistic_trips.01-23`
WHERE member_casual = "member";
SELECT COUNT (member_casual)
FROM `test-project-355707.cyclistic_trips.02-23`
WHERE member_casual = "casual";
SELECT COUNT (member_casual)
FROM `test-project-355707.cyclistic_trips.02-23`
WHERE member_casual = "member";
SELECT COUNT (member_casual)
FROM `test-project-355707.cyclistic_trips.03-23`
WHERE member_casual = "casual";
SELECT COUNT (member_casual)
FROM `test-project-355707.cyclistic_trips.03-23`
WHERE member_casual = "member";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combinde six queries to one. You want to use `UNION ALL`

It will combine the result from all three `Select` statements

Then the `Where` to filter the `causal` and `member`

```
SELECT '01-23' as month, member_casual, COUNT(*) as count
FROM test-project-355707.cyclistic_trips.01-23
WHERE member_casual IN ('casual', 'member')
GROUP BY month, member_casual
UNION ALL
SELECT '02-23' as month, member_casual, COUNT(*) as count
FROM test-project-355707.cyclistic_trips.02-23
WHERE member_casual IN ('casual', 'member')
GROUP BY month, member_casual
UNION ALL
SELECT '03-23' as month, member_casual, COUNT(*) as count
FROM test-project-355707.cyclistic_trips.03-23
WHERE member_casual IN ('casual', 'member')
GROUP BY month, member_casual
```

Answer (score 0):

To combine all these queries into one, you can use the UNION ALL operator to combine the results of multiple SELECT statements. You can also add a new column to each SELECT statement to identify the month of the data:

```
SELECT 'January' AS month, COUNT(member_casual) AS casual_count
FROM test-project-355707.cyclistic_trips.01-23
WHERE member_casual = 'casual'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'January' AS month, COUNT(member_casual) AS member_count
FROM test-project-355707.cyclistic_trips.01-23
WHERE member_casual = 'member'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'February' AS month, COUNT(member_casual) AS casual_count
FROM test-project-355707.cyclistic_trips.02-23
WHERE member_casual = 'casual'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'February' AS month, COUNT(member_casual) AS member_count
FROM test-project-355707.cyclistic_trips.02-23
WHERE member_casual = 'member'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'March' AS month, COUNT(member_casual) AS casual_count
FROM test-project-355707.cyclistic_trips.03-23
WHERE member_casual = 'casual'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'March' AS month, COUNT(member_casual) AS member_count
FROM test-project-355707.cyclistic_trips.03-23
WHERE member_casual = 'member';
```

This will return a table with four columns: month, casual_count for the number of casual trips in that month, member_count for the number of member trips in that month. Note that the AS keyword is used to assign aliases to the column names.

If you need to count the total amount or separately 'casual' and separately 'member', then you can use JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using multiple `case` clause with the aggregate function `sum()` and `union all` to combine results:

```
select '01-23' as dataset,
       sum(case when member_casual = "casual" then 1 else 0 end) as casual_count,
       sum(case when member_casual = "member" then 1 else 0 end) as member_count
from `test-project-355707.cyclistic_trips.01-23`
union all
select '02-23' as dataset,
       sum(case when member_casual = "casual" then 1 else 0 end) as casual_count,
       sum(case when member_casual = "member" then 1 else 0 end) as member_count
from `test-project-355707.cyclistic_trips.02-23`
union all
select '03-23' as dataset,
       sum(case when member_casual = "casual" then 1 else 0 end) as casual_count,
       sum(case when member_casual = "member" then 1 else 0 end) as member_count
from `test-project-355707.cyclistic_trips.03-23`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the three datasets with `union all`, then do the conditional counts with [handy BQ function `countif`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#countif):

```
select 
    countif(member_casual = 'casual') as cnt_casual,
    countif(member_casual = 'member') as cnt_member
from (
    select member_casual from `test-project-355707.cyclistic_trips.01-23`
    union all select member_casual from `test-project-355707.cyclistic_trips.02-23`
    union all select member_casual from `test-project-355707.cyclistic_trips.03-23`
) x
where member_casual in ('casual', 'member')
```

Adding a `WHERE` clause *might* help the database optimize the query, if you have more than just two distinct values.

This gives you a resultset with one row and two columns. If you wanted one row per member type instead, we can `group by` instead:

```
select member_casual, count(*) cnt 
from (
    select member_casual from `test-project-355707.cyclistic_trips.01-23`
    union all select member_casual from `test-project-355707.cyclistic_trips.02-23`
    union all select member_casual from `test-project-355707.cyclistic_trips.03-23`
) x
where member_casual in ('casual', 'member')
group by member_casual
```